# How do I see all GIT Users from my private git server?

Tags: 12.04, configuration, git

I just installed GIT server on my ubuntu 12.04 server. It works well, but I don't know all configurations. I know that i can see my pricate account using `nano ~/.gitconfig`
but how to see all users who have a working account on that server? 
I know there is some global config, but it didn't show me what I needed.

I am also searching for the groups I created and who is in that group.

Answer (score 0):

The keys of authorised users are stored in `/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys`. You can `cat` this file but you'll only see the keys, not the user names.

Read more details in the [Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).